# How do I write a test in JavaScript using the Sikuli library?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, automated-tests, sikuli, sikuli-script

I am looking to drive a macOS application like Calculator. I have pulled down the Sikuli jar file from Maven. I have watched the Joe C. video on this using Java and Eclipse. I am looking to do this in IntelliJ and to use JavaScript instead.

This will allow me to use my preferred IDE instead of a non-industry standard IDE like SikuliX.

Comment: Which Sikuli version are you using, and what do you mean drive a a macOS application? Sikuli is a Jython based language and you're trying to throw in Javascript which doesn't make sense... Jython = Python + Java not Javascript.. you'd have to re-write the code.

Comment: @MitchellMonarch But you can use Javascript because it's supported and I am using a testing framework that allows me to write a test using Javascript. One can also use Java if one chooses. Downvoting because you skimmed the homepage is not sufficient.

Comment: @JimGrigoryan I'd prefer to use Sikuli Script with JavaScript as the language. I am looking for a cross platform solution that works on multiple platforms. Sikuli Script fits that bill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that I wrote using JavaScript and the Sikuli Script jar file available on SonaType.

```js
var imports = new JavaImporter(java.io, java.lang, org.sikuli.script, org.sikuli.natives, org.junit);
with (imports) {
    var path = "/Users/dave/IdeaProjects/Sikuli/images/";
    var eight = path + "eight.png";
    var multiply = path + "multiply.png";
    var five = path + "five.png";
    var three = path + "three.png";
    var equals = path + "equals.png";
    var result = path + "result.png";

    var Screen = Java.type("org.sikuli.script.Screen");
    var App = Java.type("org.sikuli.script.App");
    var MacUtil = Java.type("org.sikuli.natives.MacUtil");
    var Assert = Java.type("org.junit.Assert");

    var s = new Screen();
    var a = new App();
    var mu = new MacUtil();

    a.setName("Calculator");

    mu.open(a);

    s.click(eight);
    s.click(multiply);
    s.click(three);
    s.click(equals);
    Assert.assertNotNull("The Image is not Correct", s.exists(result));
}
```